# Spring to serialize OffsetDateTime as a timestamp automatically

Tags: spring, datetime, serialization, java-8

I have a group of spring micro-services, and most of the responses contains `timestamp`  field

```
@NotNull
public OffsetDateTime timestamp = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

this attribute is serialized as

```
  "timestamp": {
    "offset": {
      "totalSeconds": 0,
      "id": "Z",
      "rules": {
        "transitionRules": [],
        "transitions": [],
        "fixedOffset": true
      }
    },
    "nano": 998000000,
    "year": 2019,
    "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
    "hour": 12,
    "month": "MARCH",
    "dayOfMonth": 26,
    "dayOfYear": 85,
    "minute": 20,
    "monthValue": 3,
    "second": 33
  },
```

Is there any way to configure Spring to serialize it as regular timeStamp object
 `2015-10-20T11:00:00-8:30`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Serializer like:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class OffsetDateTimeSerializer extends StdSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    public OffsetDateTimeSerializer() {
        super(OffsetDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final OffsetDateTime dateTime, final JsonGenerator generator,
                          final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    }
}
```

and annotate your fields with:

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = OffsetDateTimeSerializer.class)
```